# Is there a way to batch share albums in Google+ / Picasa?

Tags: google-plus-photos, picasa-web-albums

I just finished scanning my family's archive of photo albums and now I want to share them with my family on Google+ / Picasa.
I have some 80 albums, is there a way to share all of them at once?
I really don't want to do them one at a time.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do this with Google's command line tools.

http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/

Here's how to create a new album and upload new files to it:

**Create an album titled "funny-pics-from-reddit"**

```
stu@sente ~ $ google picasa create --title "funny-pics-from-reddit"
Created album: https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE
```

**Upload some images to that album**

```
stu@sente ~ $ google picasa post --title "funny-pics-from-reddit" *.jpg
Loading file 1IH46.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
Loading file 8518.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
Loading file 8mWVg.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
Loading file aMgoD.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
Loading file B5OzH.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
Loading file BdA1X.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
Loading file cinkh.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
Loading file Il45S.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
Loading file s8mYA.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
Loading file VNXqI.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
Loading file YS0ri.jpg to album funny-pics-from-reddit
```

**Thats all!**

*you can also get a link for sharing*

```
stu@sente ~ $ google picasa list-albums --title 'funny-pics-from-reddit"
funny-pics-from-reddit,https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE
```

*or get a link for each of images within the album*

```
stu@sente ~ $ google picasa list -link --title "funny-pics-from-reddit"
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197402363448466
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197407826357506
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197411671223314
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197415991037282
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197418880127170
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197428322810098
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197433154709954
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197440054494146
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197445495462290
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197447926728866
https://picasaweb.google.com/108147164794119808099/FunnyPicsFromReddit?authkey=Gv1sRgCNeGh-vqrJLlrgE#5676197458703531074
```

Comment: Awesome! I can't wait to try this out.